# How does an Android Qt 5.3 Application load custom Java classes?

Tags: java, android, qt, java-native-interface

I am porting a Qt application to Android, and to communicate with parts of the system, it uses a custom Java library packaged with the application.  The problem is that I can't find a place to load the Java classes I need to invoke.

Normally I would do this in JNI_OnLoad, but Qt 5.3 hides that away in its own internal code. This means I have to load the class from a native thread as the Qt application starts up because the QApplication is started in its own thread. The system class loader is available from this context, but not one that can find classes in my APK.

Another option would be to get hold of the classloader that would find the local classes.  Browsing through the Qt code, I see that it does grab hold of the classloader as it starts up, but again it is down in the Qt private code.  It can't be accessed from the application.

I thought this would be a reasonably common thing to do in a Qt Android application, and am surprised it's causing me such grief.  I'm hoping I am missing something obvious.

Does anyone know the right place to retrieve a java class instance using JNI in a Qt 5.3 application?

Ignoring error checking, the code snippet below is what I'm trying to do.  I've verified the class has been included in the dex file with the expected name, but the class is never found (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown).

```
  // Given a JNIEnv, find MyClass, and cache it away for later use
  jclass localClass = env->FindClass("my/class/in/apk/MyClass");
  j_MyClass = reinterpret_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(localClass));
  env->DeleteLocalRef(localClass);
```

Comment: How are you creating the instance? Which line is throwing the Exception?

Comment: FindClass returns NULL, and sets the 'NoClassDefFoundError' exception. The JNIEnv instance is retrieved through a vm reference, attaching to the current thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't embracing the Qt way.  I couldn't cache the jclass myself, but using the Qt class QAndroidJniObject achieves the same effect.  Under the hood, Qt caches away referenced jclass and jmethod as they are referenced.  There is a bit of extra overhead in the Qt implementation rather than doing it yourself, but in my situation this isn't a problem.  On the up-side, it simplifies JNI code significantly.

In summary, just use the QAndroidJniObject class, and forget about caching jclass/jmethod references yourself.

As a dodgy example with no error checking:

```
void JNICALL Java_my_java_class_MyClass_myNativeMethod
  (JNIEnv* env, jobject, jobjectArray objectArray)
{
  QAndroidJniObject obj(env->GetObjectArrayElement(objectArray, 0));
  QAndroidJniObject jstr = obj.callObjectMethod<jstring>("getString");
  QString qtstr = jstr.toString();
}
```

This is all pretty obvious in retrospect :)